# Loop a list through awk

Tags: awk

I have two files: data.csv and list.txt. Here's an example of what they look like

data.csv:

```
"John","red","4"
"Basketball","orange","2"
"The Mike","blue","94"
"Lizard","purple","3"
"Johnny","pink","32"
```

list.txt:

```
Mike
John
purple
32
```

Now, I am trying to figure out how I can make a loop

```
awk -F "\"*,\"*" '/**LIST ITEM**/ {print $1}' data.csv > output.txt
```

where the command runs for each line of list.txt, replacing **LIST ITEM**. How can this be accomplished?

I'm running this though Terminal on MacOSX 10.5.7.

EDIT:

The desired output for the above example would be

```
The Mike
John
Johnny
Lizard
Johnny
```

EDIT2:

To be more clear, I am trying to avoid doing this:

```
awk -F "\"*,\"*" '/Mike/ {print $1}' data.csv
awk -F "\"*,\"*" '/John/ {print $1}' data.csv
awk -F "\"*,\"*" '/purple/ {print $1}' data.csv
awk -F "\"*,\"*" '/32/ {print $1}' data.csv
```

And instead, run it in one command, somehow looping through all the lines of list.txt.

Comment: The command should run replacing \*\*LIST ITEM\*\* with 'Mike', then 'John', then 'purple', then '32'.

Comment: It would be quite helpful if your sample input included `LIST ITEM` somewhere (assuming it's literal) as well as providing desired output

Comment: @Julien When you say `**LIST ITEM**`, it appears you mean the first field of your CSV, yes?  Also, I believe your desired output is wrong, there is an extra `Johnny` line, yes?

Comment: When I say \*\*LIST ITEM\*\* I mean a line from list.txt. Hence an item from the list, or list item.

Comment: `awk -F "\"*,\"*" '/32/ {print $1}' data.csv` would yield `Johnny`, unless I am mistaken.

Comment: Just checked, it yields `"Johnny` which makes sense. There will actually be `"` at the beginning of all lines, but that's only a minor problem.

Comment: @Julien: gotcha, see answer.

Comment: Generally, you can use the awk split function to take a string then parse it into an array that you can loop over. E.g. `awk 'BEGIN{split("one two",myarr," ");for(each in myarr)print "got",myarr[each]}'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This meets the order of your desired output:

```
$ awk -F, '
    NR == FNR {field1[$0] = $1; next}
    {
      for (line in field1) 
        if (line ~ $0) 
          print field1[line]
    }
  ' data.csv list.txt 
"The Mike"
"John"
"Johnny"
"Lizard"
"Johnny"
```

This reads the data.csv file into memory, mapping the whole line to field1. Then, each line of the list.txt file is checked against each element of the field1 array.

If the data file is much larger than the list file, then it would make more sense to hold the smaller file in memory and loop over the larger file a line at a time:

```
$ awk -F, '
    NR == FNR {list[$1]; next}
    {
      for (item in list) 
        if ($0 ~ item) 
          print $1
    }
  ' list.txt data.csv 
"John"
"The Mike"
"Lizard"
"Johnny"
"Johnny"
```

Comment: What if both files are very large? Is it just whichever is bigger?

Comment: This is great, now what if I only wanted it to match the beginning of the lines in data.csv?

Comment: @Julien, this might work for you too: `grep -f list.txt data.csv | cut -d, -f1`, but you only get "Johnny" once. It's a more lightweight pipeline but I can't tell if it would meet your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

 while read -r line; do 
   awk -F '^"|","|"$' '$0 ~ line{print $2}' line="$line" data.csv
 done < list.txt
```

#### Proof of Concept

```
$ while read -r line; do awk -F '^"|","|"$' '$0 ~ line{print $2}' line="$line" data.csv; done < list.txt
The Mike
John
Johnny
Lizard
Johnny
```

This field separator deals with embedded quotes and/or commas

Comment: It's not printing the second Johnny on my system... I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear on what you're trying to do:  replace **LIST ITEM** with what?  Just looking for a match anywhere and outputting the first field?  Also, your example `list.txt` appears to match anywhere in the line, which could potentially be problematic:  what if `list.txt` at some point contains the line `e`?  That would match all but the last line of your sample `data.csv`.

```
awk -F '^"?|"?,"?|"$?' 'BEGIN {
                          # read list.txt into an array
                          while (getline pat < "list.txt") {
                            pats[pat] = 1
                          }
                          close("list.txt")
                        }
                        {
                          # skip empty field before leading "
                          if ($1 == "") {
                            res = $2
                          } else {
                            res = $1
                          }
                          # scan record for patterns stored earlier,
                          # output the first real data field (res) if
                          # found
                          for (pat in pats) {
                            if ($0 ~ pat) {
                              print res
                            }
                          }
                        }' data.csv
```

This is a bit more complex than it could be; your field separator doesn't deal with the optional leading quotation mark on the first field or the optional trailing one on the last field.  Mine does, but at the price that if it's there the first field will be empty (the empty string before `^"?`).  It also doesn't try to deal with embedded quotes.  A dedicated CSV parser would be a better idea if you need to support random generalized CSV.

Comment: I see why, now, after reading glenn jackman's answer

Comment: @Julien: Your [proposed edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/187) should have been a comment. Post it as a comment here if you still have a question about geekosaur's answer.